# React/Express Fetch Request Not Displaying Array of Json Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a React client trying to use the 'fetch' api to make a GET request to a node.js Express API I made. I have CORS enabled and have looked through many questions on here and cannot figure out why the get request will not display the data on my localhost React app. In the console log it displays 
[In the console log it displays this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmQPi.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Drinker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/getCustomers', {
               mode: 'no-cors', // 'cors' by default
               headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     }}).then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 304) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong ...');
        }
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data.results);
        this.setState({ data: data.results, isLoading: false });

        }
      ).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({ error, isLoading: false });
  });


  }


  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <h1>
        loading...
        </h1>
      )
    }

    return(
      <ul>
           {this.state.data.map(drinker =>
             <li>
               <p>{drinker.name}</p>
             </li>
           )}
         </ul>
    );
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I use postman and get a good request every time. This is my postman response to the url I'm making the fetch to...

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "name": "Jack",
        "address": "NJ"
    },
    {
        "name": "Steve",
        "address": "NJ"
    },
    {
        "name": "Denny",
        "address": "NJ"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "NJ"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Check the networks tab of the Developer Tools in your browser. Does the request succeed? Also, you set the data as `hits` in your state, but you are mapping over `this.state.data`.

Comment: It gives a 200 response with the correct json the first time then every consecutive time I get a 304 which means the data requested has not changed. So it is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer, my Express app was sending responses as...

```
  res.status(200); // sends a status code
  res.json({results}); // sends results received from sql
```

but I changed it to this and it works now...

```
  res.status(200); // sends a status code
  res.send(JSON.stringify(results)); // sends results recieved from sql
```

I still don't really understand why it wouldn't work sent as json but sent as a string of text from Express, React now displays the data.

Comment: I am also following you, it is correct, but how would you handle {Users: [{}]} as most of time we have to send more object name with results. mean `res.send({Users: JSON.stringify(results)});`

Answer (score 0):

`response.ok` is `true` only if the status code is between 200-299. Since the request returns 304 it will be `false`. That's why data doesn't appear when you reload the page. Refer to the Mozilla documentation for the properties of `response` from the `fetch` API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Properties

Comment: I tried upping the status code range and it now gives me the error above in the link in my question edit